# C# - Emgu cv How to load an image from a folder using CvInvoke.cvLoadImage("ClassPic1.jpg") as intptr and access it

Tags: invoke, emgucv, intptr, loadimage

How to load an image from a specific folder using Emgu cv CvInvoke.cvLoadImage(...)?I am tryng to do it like this

```
    IntPtr inputImage = CvInvoke.cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\...\\ClassPic1.jpg");
```

Is that ok? If so, How am i gonna access it later as an Emgu.CV.Image file so that i will do my image processing on it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should probably use the following method to load the image:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("..\\..\\MyImage.jpg");// path can be absolute or relative.
```

this img1 variable can be accessed later to perform manipulations on it.

check this link for more details.
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images

Comment: I know that what i just want to know is how to directly use the open cv functions on Emgu cv using cvInvoke.Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV functions are in CvInvoke class

so:
CvInvoke.

those are all static functions.